# Java webapp code moved to library cannot resolve HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, web-applications, dependency-management

I recently moved a bunch of classes from a webapp to some standalone library.
Eclipse complained that `HttpServletRequest` was not resolved, so I added *Web App Library* to my `Java Build Path/Libraries` (following StackOverflow guidance)

=> Didn't change a thing although "Web App Libraries" is now included in my Libraries.


**How can I get HttpServletRequest to be resolved without webapp dependancies?**

**Edit: Removing "Web App Libraries" and adding servlet-api.jar found in Apache6 ./lib/ folder did the trick.**

I just hope I am not creating a dependancy on Tomcat version.

Comment: Important: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project

Comment: Does not apply to libraries. All these posts assumne you have control over Target Runtime which is not true for Libraries.

Comment: My main intention was that you need a servlet container to use such libraries (`servlet-api.jar`) :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the edit : Removing "Web App Libraries" and adding servlet-api.jar found in Apache6 ./lib/ folder did the trick.